# Is this answer correct for this set Qn?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, compactness

$\left \{(x_1,x_2) \in \Bbb R^2 : x_1^2 + x_2^2 \leq 1 \text{ and } x_1 \leqslant 0 \text{ and } x_2 \leqslant 0\right\}$

I found that it is closed because all boundaries are in set and it is bounded, so can I say that it is compact?

Comment: Yes, you can say. Actually, a subset of $\Bbb R^2$ is compact **if and only if** it is closed and bounded. Look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heine%E2%80%93Borel_theorem

Comment: What exactly is/was your difficulty? This Q is immediately answered by one of the most basic theorems in general topology.. So what is the background? Are you doing a course on general topology?

Comment: Sir, I started to study topology last week without any background. I apologize

Comment: @SteveJosh No need to apologise! But on this site it is helpful if you can give a little more background. I commented rather curtly because unfortunately many people try to abuse this site by treating it as a homework answering service!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is true that it is closed because it contains its boundary, but perhaps that it is not that easy to prove that that set (let us call it $X$) contains its boundary.

The set $X$ is the intersection of $3$ sets:

- $X_1=\bigl\{(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2\mid x^2+y^2\leqslant1\bigr\}$;
- $X_2=\bigl\{(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2\mid x\leqslant0\bigr\}$;
- $X_3=\bigl\{(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2\mid y\leqslant0\bigr\}$.

In order to prove that $X$ is closed it is enough to prove that each $X_k$ ($k\in\{1,2,3\}$) is closed. And $X_1$ is closed because $X_1=f^{-1}\bigl((-\infty,1]\bigr)$ (where $f(x,y)=x^2+y^2$) and $(-\infty,1]$ is continuous. A similar argument shows that $X_2$ and $X_3$ are closed too.

And $X$ is compact since it is closed and bounded.